# How can Alice share with Bob a link to a Slack message posted in a channel both Alice and Bob can access, but via a different workspace of a same org?

Tags: slack, links

Alice and Bob belong to the same Slack org but different Slack workspaces inside that org: Alice is in `aliceworkspace` workspace, Bob is in `bobworkspace` workspace.

Alice and Bob are both in a channel that was made accessible to all Slack workspaces of that org. Alice wants to share with Bob a link pointing to a message in that channel. However, when Alice tries to share that link with Bob, the link URL points to the workspace that Alice belongs to, e.g. https://aliceworkspace.slack.com/archives/CA159ADVSVD/p156981000984, and Bob can't access it.

How can Alice share a link to Bob that Bob can access?

---

Alice got the link via the "copy link" menu item available for the message that Alice wants to share:

[image]